# Working with large csv files . How to insert csv data in MySQL database using python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pyspark

I am interested in how to insert for example 10 GB .csv file into MySQL database. I was using pandas and pyspark to read csv file, then adding csv header to list (if csv file does not have header, I was adding it with spark). Then I was parsing list and replacing characters for MySQL insert code -->

```
mydb.cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," + column_names + ", PRIMARY KEY (id))")
```

Then I was adding whole rows without header line to list , then parsing again to replace `'name'` to `` `name` `` . So I was editing list for

```
query = "insert into `"+ table_name +"` (" + column_names + ") values (" + row_value + ")"
```

This was working perfectly for small sized csv files. But for large files the process is crashing because of low memory.

But what about large csv files ? Is there any workaround for inserting large csv file data into MySQL ? Or do you have code examples for working with large csv files to insert them into MySQL without low memory issue ?

I thought that if I split large csv file into small ones and insert then, it would be better for memory. And may be there is some more better ways for inserting that size of data into MySQL .

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL can read CSV files directly using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Why do it through Python?

Comment: But it needs table to be created first right ? So I have to read csv file to see names for columns . I want automated way of uploading data that's why I want to do it with Python.

Comment: Python can read the first line of the CSV to get the column names and create the table. Then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the contents into the table. But where will you get the datatypes from?

Comment: Anyway, `pandas.read_csv()` has a `chunksize` optional argument. You can use that to process the file in smaller chunks. Then you can use `df.to_sql()` to insert them into the table.

Comment: Yeah, I rewrote my code with `LOAD DATA INFILE` . It is working perfectly without low memory issues  Now I am waiting for results . Thank you for your time @barmar

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use Python and Pandas rather than the faster way of having MySQL read the csv file directly, then use the Pandas syntax for writing to sql.  If you can load the csv file into memory, it ought to be fine for loading into MySQL as well.  Here's a toy example of code for writing to MySQL, there are many options that you may want, so see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html for details.

```
df.to_sql(name=table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few issues with what you're doing, in any case what I offer will be the same

1st of all, if you're trying to process single row inserts, perhaps the SQL server can't pick on the velocity of requests, and crashes, then maybe a timer set foe delay would help

2nd of all, a single INSERT command can handle multiple lines, so instead of pushing one row at a time to a table, you can do puah them in the paces of thousands

I would suggeat somwthing like the following:

```
import time

rows = pd.DataFrame() #your df to be inserted

insert_header = "INSERT INTO table_name "
insert_cols = "(" + ",".join(rows.columns) + ")"

to_sql = rows[rows.columns[0:]].apply(
    lambda x: "('" + "','".join(x.fillna(0).astype(str)) + "'),",
    axis=1)

counter = to_sql.size
jump = 1000

for i in range(0, counter,jump): #jump
    print(jump)
    to = min(i + jump, counter)
    sql_values = " VALUES " + ''.join(to_sql.iloc[i:to])
    exec_sql = insert_header + insert_cols + sql_values
    exec_sql = exec_sql[:-1]
    cursor.execute(exec_sql)
    connection.commit()
    time.sleep(2)
```